# scrapy from script output in json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running `scrapy` in a python script

```
def setup_crawler(domain):
    dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    spider = ArgosSpider(domain=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    reactor.run()
```

it runs successfully and stops but where is the result ? I want the result in json format, how can I do that?

```
result = responseInJSON
```

like we do using command

```
scrapy crawl argos -o result.json -t json
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set [`FEED_FORMAT`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_FORMAT) and [`FEED_URI`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-uri) settings manually:

```
settings.overrides['FEED_FORMAT'] = 'json'
settings.overrides['FEED_URI'] = 'result.json'
```

If you want to get the results into a variable you can define a [`Pipeline`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) class that would collect items into the list. Use the `spider_closed` signal handler to see the results:

```
import json

from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        results.append(dict(item))

results = []
def spider_closed(spider):
    print results

# set up spider    
spider = TestSpider(domain='mydomain.org')

# set up settings
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.overrides['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = {'__main__.MyPipeline': 1}

# set up crawler
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)

# start crawling
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

FYI, look at how Scrapy [parses command-line arguments](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py).

Also see: [Capturing stdout within the same process in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654834/capturing-stdout-within-the-same-process-in-python).

Comment: what if i dont want it in a file? instead i want it in a variable?? result??

Comment: @WasifKhalil I've updated the answer, give it a try.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'overrides'

Answer (score 23):

I managed to make it work simply by adding the `FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` to the `CrawlerProcess` constructor, using the basic Scrapy API tutorial code as follows:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
'FEED_URI': 'result.json'
})
```

Comment: Definitely an easy solution for testing! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Easy!

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl argos -o result.json -t json".split())
```

Put that script where you put `scrapy.cfg`

Answer (score 4):

```
settings.overrides
```

doesn't seem to work anymore it must be deprecated. Now, the correct way to pass those settings is to modify the project settings with the [set](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.settings.BaseSettings.set) method:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'json')
settings.set('FEED_URI', 'result.json')
```