# Scrapy 1.0 - Getting return value after running from python script

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the below code to run my crawler from a python script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

where my `MySpider` returns an object.

How can I get the return value from this? Please keep in mind this is Scrapy 1.0. All the examples I found are for older versions of Scrapy.

The above code is from : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution would be to implement custom item pipeline to store your results in a file -- and read the results later.

Alternatively you can do this with configuring the export in Scrapy too. For example export the items in a file called `results.json`:

```
settings.overrides['FEED_FORMAT'] = 'json'
settings.overrides['FEED_URI'] = 'results.json'
```

To avoid the temporal file you should use a custom pipeline class and handle your results on the `spider_closed` signal.

You can refer to this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23574703/3941341

Comment: I don't want to read results from a file. I want the object. Is there any way that could be done?

Comment: Please read the answer I linked to. It describes how to do that too.

Comment: The answer is for an older version of Scrapy. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try it actually? Because from the release notes I do not see any changes which would affect this solution.

Comment: Yeah I did. The crawler.py has changed and so has the Crawler class. It now needs a spidercls along with settings.

Comment: This actually works if I remove the deprecated stuff.
http://blog.tryolabs.com/2011/09/27/calling-scrapy-python-script/