# How do I add `-o` argument in scrapy while running it programmatically in python

Tags: python, scrapy

Suppose I have a code, where I run the scrapy crawler with python.

```
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    data = str(self.prothom_date_lineedit.text())


    process.crawl(ArticleCommentsSpider, data)

    self.statusBar.showMessage("Scraping from prothom alo")

    process.start() # this starts the crawling. But I want to save the json file to a file.
```

As in command line, I always use `scrapy crawl <proj_name> -o out.json`.

How do I use this `-o out.json` in python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574636/scrapy-from-script-output-in-json This may be useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrapy from script output in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574636/scrapy-from-script-output-in-json)