# Capture/redirect console output to file

Tags: python, file-io, console, stdout, python-behave

So, I believe this issue can be applied to any python file generating logs to console.

I am trying to capture the output generated while running a behave test(all code is in python3.x).

Or more precisely: I am trying to capture the live generated console output to a file for a particular function of interest in the python code.

My aim is to capture the console logs printed (on `stdout`) the moment it hits a particular function in the python code.

I usually do a `behave data_base_scenarios.feature` without quotes on Ubuntu 18.04.
I would like to capture the complete output as it is directed to the console to file.

On StackOverflow, after searching for a while, I tried some of the methods described here: [Capturing stdout within the same process in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654834/capturing-stdout-within-the-same-process-in-python/3113913#3113913). I also found this: https://capturer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Unfortunately, I don't see anything captured. 
I have taken care to set up the behave environment to generate the logs. For example all these flags are appropriately and explicitly set to generate outputs:
`context.config.stdout_capture = True`, `context.config.log_capture = True`. 
What am I missing with behave environment.

Behave framework also provides a variable within "context". Its "context.stdout_capture". But unfortunately it contains nothing.

In short Behave prints on the console

```
  Captured logging:
    INFO:database.system.status: MyDatabase is online.
    INFO:database.system.status: MyDatabase is now offline.
    INFO:database.system.status: MyDatabase has now initiated.
```

I just want to dump the above "Captured Logging" console output to a file for analysis.

How can I do it? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on how you're doing it, but if you're using `behave_main`, then you can do something like the following:

```
from behave.__main__ import main as behave_main

args = ['--outfile=/path/to/your/log/directory/output.log']
behave_main(args)
```

If you're running your tests via the command line, then use the `-o`, or `--outfile`, flag and append your log name.